# composer scripts use older php version

Tags: php, shell, composer-php, version, bash

I host more and more sites on webfaction. Great provider! I ran into some problems though which I think are Linux related. Hope someone can help.

SSH command `php -v` defaults to an older version of php, So I created an alias in my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias composer="php70 $HOME/composer.phar"
alias php="php70"
```

When I preform a `php -v` now it returns PHP 7.0. So far, so good!

```
PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  4 2015 12:58:58) ( NTS )
```

But now when I run a composer install and put a `php -v` in the scripts -> post-install-cmd list in my `composer.json` file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php -v",
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Now tt returns the old php version again, see this screenshot:

[image: screenshot composer install]

Maybe this seems completely logic to you guys/girls, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: See same [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2000) in laravel github.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Composer doesn't use your alias to execute PHP.

You could use `php70 -v` in `composer.json`, but its better to 
symlink the newer PHP version to `/bin/php`, so that Composer can pick it up:

---

Create a `~/bin` folder

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Then symlink the newer PHP version `/usr/local/bin/php70` to just`~/bin/php`

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php70 ~/bin/php
```

Finally, add this line to `.bash_profile` to append this folder to your environment variable PATH.

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: @jens-a-koch: Thank you very much for this detailed solution! It worked out great.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Any other alternative? I can't create that symbolic link in my server. I get _Permission denied_. Why isn't composer running the correct version anyway? I made an alias, and set an set php7 in the PATH, and I'm also running composer with php7 so... :(

Comment: seems like a working solution without need to change the base php version of server

Comment: +100 if I could, this is the only solution that worked for me.